# Assigning a random password while using Devise

Tags: devise, passwords

Here's a breakdown of the situation -

**Desired behavior:** user can sign_up through Devise gem by providing their email address only. Web app generates and db stores a temporary password, unknown to user.

**Logic:** This is meant to be a 'gradual sign-up' process to a web application still under construction (we want to begin capturing potential users without providing access to the web app as it's still in partial development). The email is to be used for communication purposes until final release.

**Problem:** Devise gem requires user to input email && password during sign_up process. We've found no obvious way to circumvent the dual requirement. User failing to provide password generates error.

**Potential solution:** After searches and many tries, this seems to be the closest alternative (found here).

```
generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
user = User.create!(:email => email, :password => generated_password)
```

**Question:** While this *potential solution* makes sense, we're REALLY new to this and don't understand in which file to place this code within the Devise configuration, and how to call it.

All help appreciated.

LM

Answer (score -1):

OK, I kept digging until I found what I was looking for ([here](http://goo.gl/ksUQVs)) - maybe it can help you too.

In your model:

```
  before_validation :generate_password, :on => :create

 def generate_password
    o =  [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'), (0..9)].map{|i| i.to_a}.flatten
    self.password = self.password_confirmation = (0..16).map{ o[rand(o.length)] }.join if     self.password.blank?
  end
```